# How to configure custom endpoint in webapi .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to configure custom endpoint on webapi .netcore 2.2 like `/api/v1/{product}/{service}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [aspnet-api-versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning)

Here is the sample

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning -Version 2.2.0
```

Then in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        });
}
```

And finally register in the controller

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController:Controller
```

You can view my blog [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2018/04/26/asp-net-core-api-versioning/)

Comment: But I want only with custom attributes {product}/{service}

Comment: what ís product and service stand for

Answer (score 0):

It works well when I use below api action and test with url like `https://localhost:5001/api/v1/hello/world`.

Api action:

```
[HttpGet("/api/v1/{service}/{product}")]       
public  IActionResult  Payment([FromRoute(Name = "service")]string service, [FromRoute(Name = "product")]string product)
 {
 }
```